# wamp, websockets, wampy.js and other. How to get outgoing message sent by myself?

Tags: javascript, frontend, wamp, chat, messaging

How could I get outgoing message? I am a publisher, but in the same time I'm a  subscriber. When I publish a message, subscribe's callback doesn't work. For example, in wampy.js onEvent fires only when I **receive** message (as it should be, of course). But I'm creating a chat. As in any chat I should see my own messages. So, how could I get my own messages? I'm breaking my back to make it right, without duct tapes. Maybe I should to do something on backend? Have any ideas?

```
ws.subscribe(topic, {
onEvent: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var message = data.argsList[0];
    if(message !== undefined){
        newMessage(message);
    }

}});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code which you have tried. This will allow people to identify the problem and suggest solutions. Please see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I found it! That wasn't easy, but I have need to read a code of wampy.js more attentive. There is an option "exclude_me: false", which you can pass as an  argument in publish() and which is true as default. :)

Example of client code (using wampy.js):

```
function sendMessage(){
    var message = getMessageFromField();
    if(message !== '' || message !== undefined){
        ws.publish(topic, message, function(){
        }, {exclude_me: false});
    }
    $(messageField).val('');
}
```